Estimate the norm of inverse matrix
I am aware that there are already quite a lot of similar posts regarding this topic in this forum, however, until now I couldn't find any suitable answer to my problem.
I have some matrix $A=A(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $x\in E$ for some bounded set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. I was able to show that the matrix $A$ is invertible for any $x\in E$, but without calculating the inverse (which I think would be quit difficult in this case). I want to derive an upper bound for the norm of $A^{-1}(x)$ with respect to some matrix norm, let's say we consider the usual Frobenius norm. If I am able to show that the norm $\| A(x)\|$ is bounded below and above for any $x\in E$ by some constants $0<C_1\leq C_2<\infty$, i.e. $C_1 \leq \| A(x)\| \leq C_2$ for all $x\in E$, can we then already infer an upper bound for $\|A^{-1}(x)\|$? I know that in general there holds the lower bound
$$\|A^{-1}(x)\| \geq \frac{1}{\|A(x)\|},$$
but I am not aware of a suitable upper bound. I am very thankful for any suggestions and think this is a quite interesting problem that many other readers may find helpful!
